# How to connect my local db to deployed site

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, heroku

I have created and deployed web site using Spring Boot on heroku.com. It has been deployed fine, but when I open the site it is blank because it does not get any data from my local PostgreSQL DB. I tried moving my DB to the Heroku database but failed. Maybe you can advise me on how to connect my local DB to the website on heroku or explain what the problem is.

Comment: Why would you want to expose your local database from a client computer to the Heroku instance? If anything, even if you manage to get that working it would mean your computer must be on 24/7 or the website won't work. I would suggest retrying to get your database online somewhere instead. 
If you really really really want to expose your database, make sure the Heroku accepts outside traffic on the database port to your network (i.e. home IP) and make sure to port forward your db port in the firewall to your local machine.

Comment: thanks for the response! could you please recommend where i can host my db?

Comment: There are many options available (cloudproviders / vps / etc).  Just google for them. I have no experience with Heroku but I can imagine that they can host that as well.